# Remove element from multiple files with python

Tags: python, replace

I have the next, script, it removes commas from multiple files in a folder. It works OK, but I would like to "improve". At some point I have to store in memory the whole file an then write it. I've tried with readlines reading and writing line by line but in the best of the cases I end up with a with a the first part as originally is and a second part with the file with the commas removed.

```
import os

os.chdir(raw_input("Folder with files to remove \" (comma): "))

for files in os.listdir(os.getcwd()):
    f = open(files, "r")
    rep = f.read().replace('"','')
    f.close()

    f = open(files, "w")
    f.write(rep)
    f.close()
```

This is a demo file

```
"GO:0016925"    0.613185459363216
"GO:0007029"    0.617740206445514
"GO:0006310"    0.617740206445514
```

Comment: You will need to read the original file in chunks, writing chunks to a temporary file. After finishing the whole file you will have to delete the original and rename the temp to the original name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a temporary file :

```
from tempfile import mkstemp
from shutil import move
import os

os.chdir(raw_input("Folder with files to remove \" (comma): "))

for files in os.listdir(os.getcwd()):
    #create temp file
    f, p = mkstemp()
    #do the copy with the replace
    with open(p,'w') as new:
       with open(files) as old:
          for line in old:
            new.write(line.replace(('"','')))
    os.close(f)
    #replace the old file by the new one
    os.remove(files)
    move(p, files)
```